# MS Access throwing error 2001 when running VBA script to make a directory in a Macro or as sub script

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the following VBA script in MS Access to check for a directory and make it if it does not exist:

```
Public Function MakeReportDirct()

Dim fDate As String
Dim sFolderPath As String
Dim oFSO As Object


fDate = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM")
sFolderPath = "\\satco-file01\COMPANYSHAREDFOLDERS\Reporting\Nuvo\Daily Reports\" & fDate

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If oFSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
End

End If

MkDir sFolderPath

End Function
```

When I run the code alone in the VBA window, it works perfectly. However, when I try to run the code from a Macro or when I try to call from another VBA script:

```
Public Function ChartwellVendor()

Call MakeReportDirct
Call ChartwellVendorExport
Call ChartwellVendorEmail


End Function
```

It gives the "Macro Single Step" error:[2001](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY1uW.png)

I have enabled every location I can think of (the database location, the export location, the location the directory will be created) as a "Trusted Location".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [End statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/end-statement) *"Terminates execution immediately"*.

When you run `MakeReportDirct` alone, that accomplishes what you want: `MkDir` is not executed when the folder already exists.

But when you run it from within `ChartwellVendor`, you want other procedures to run after `MakeReportDirct`.  However, the `End` statement terminates ***all*** further processing, so those other procedures don't run.

You could avoid that problem by replacing `End` with `Exit Function`.  Then `MakeReportDirct` could terminate but still allow processing to continue with the next line in `ChartwellVendor`

Another approach would be to flip the logic of your `If` block condition.  If the folder does not exist, run `MkDir` inside that code block.

```vb
If Not oFSO.FolderExists(sFolderPath) Then
    MkDir sFolderPath
End If
```

Comment: Well, definitely a facepalm moment. It was definitely the ```End``` statement causing the issue.  I also implemented the ```If Not``` ... It does streamline it a bit more.  Thanks for the help!!  Cheers!